# Power Apps - Premium Connectors

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, powerapp, dataverse

We have a Power App, with the following Connectors:

[image]

So do any of these Connectors require a Power Apps Premium License ?

Thanks

**EDIT** Based on @Rob Windsor reply, I followed this [link](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/)  where i can see that `Dataverse` is a Premium Connector:

[image]

But at the same time if i try to add a Dataverse Connector inside our Power Apps i will not get any Premium icons:

[image]

while other Connectors (such as SQL Server Connector) will show the Premium Icons:

[image]

so why are we getting these conflicting results? and which is accurate? could it be that power apps are Premium under certain tenants, and are not Premium under other tenants?

As on this [link](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/) it provides the info for public users, while when I am inside Power Apps I am logged in using my Office 365 account..

Answer (score 0):

You can go to https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/ and search for the connector by name. Premium connectors will have the word **Premium** shown under the name.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your helpful reply, can you please check my edit ? i provided more info based on your reply. thanks